# Matlab Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch

Tags: matlab

My code is as below:
my `dbFeaturesTop` and side is a matrix of size 700x128. May I know which part cause the error please?
I run this line then error shows.

Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

```
Error in FYPGUI>btnTrainNeuralNetwork_Callback (line 411)
x ( :, sample ) = [(cell2mat(dbFeaturesTop(sample)))
(cell2mat(dbFeaturesSide(sample)))];

x = zeros ( 2, noOfSamples );
x ( :, sample ) = [(cell2mat(dbFeaturesTop(sample))) (cell2mat(dbFeaturesSide(sample)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

First store the matrix in a temporary variable:

```
tempMat = [(cell2mat(dbFeaturesTop(sample))) (cell2mat(dbFeaturesSide(sample)))];
```

Print out the size of that matrix. The error is that `x(:, sample)` does not match the dimensions of tempMat. `sample` should be a vector such that the dimensions should match up.